# How to make table auto adjust in different screen resolutions

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'll try to be very modest on this one because I've been stuck in this problem for an hour already. I created my very own header-bar sort-of and [here](http://postimg.org/image/e3jpn9pwb/) is the normal view of it in my own resolution. But whenever I try to view it on my friend's netbook (which has lower resolution), it will display something like [this](http://postimg.org/image/k5141ob19/).

Here's my CSS:

```
#header_table {
width: 100%;
min-width: 100%;
height: 55px;
margin: auto;
background-color: #EEEEEE;
color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

And on the left cell of the table I put

```
<td width = 70%>
```

I tried putting

```
<td style="width:70%; min-width:70%;">
```

but still it won't work.

How can I make that table cell on the right adjust or move so that the button won't be under the textbox?

Comment: I think the problem is in the width of the textbox and button, not the td's width. The elements in the right cell, just wont fit that remaining 30%.

Comment: It worked thanks, but can't I make it to stick to the right side of the header, like whatever resolution you'll use to view it, it is always docked on the far right of the header bar? thanks again

Comment: Give your input & submit button a percentage width, like 80% for input, 20% for button.

Comment: Alternatively, you could try a different approach than a table. Try floating elements left and right like this: https://jsfiddle.net/zx5Lgz78/